# Trying to create multiple oscillators

Tags: web-audio-api

I am struggling to understand how to create an array of WebAudio oscillators, such as osc[i].
I have been able to construct single oscillators such as

```
let oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
oscillator.frequency.value = 493.88; //B4
```

I have looked at articles such as [".. Polyphonic Synthesis"](https://blog.chrislowis.co.uk/2013/06/10/playing-multiple-notes-web-audio-api.html) but I don't understand what is happening with the author's "compact" code!

Comment: I have found a simpler solution to my problem (which was to play a sequence of notes). This solution is simpler than my attempt above to create an array of oscillators and it simply creates a new oscillator each time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261030/web-audio-start-and-stop-oscillator-then-start-it-again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a loop:

```js
const oscs = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  const oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
  oscillator.frequency.value = 110 * 2 ** i;
  oscs.push(oscillator);
}
```

this will create 7 oscillators (A2 to A8)